# Minecraft wont let me sign in

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have Minecraft already downloaded but I never paid for it, I am willing to pay because that seems that it will actually work but when I try to create an account it doesn't let me.

I have made several different emails trying but when the account is created and I try to login it won't work.

I click to login button with the correct information but when I click login it just doesn't load, it just sits there and doesn't say anything like "invalid information", but when I try to use the same email again I can't because it already is an account.

I am trying to login on minecrat.net to make the account.

Answer (score 0):

If the notice says "Invalid email or password", it could be password issues. Have you tried clicking the "Forgot Password" button on the login page and resetting your password using the prompts? Perhaps then when you try to sign in, you were just getting the password wrong the whole time.

Comment: Yes ive tried that a couple times and its still not working

Comment: @manda You should have mentioned that in your original post.

Comment: I thought i did sorry i meant to but i must have forgotten